# "Invite fellow experts" widget displayed on private beta sites has unclickable "Recipient" and "Message (Optional)" labels

Tags: bug, design, private-beta, accessibility

On [sites in private beta](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta), a widget is shown in the right sidebar to invite fellow experts via email:

[image: "Invite fellow experts" box shown on private beta sites, containing 2 text fields with the labels "Recipient" and "Message (Optional)" respectively.]

When hovering over the labels "Recipient" and "Message (Optional)" (yes, that's a single `<label>`), the cursor changes to a hand (at least in Firefox on macOS), suggesting that they are clickable, but nothing happens when I click on them.

The [expected behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) is that the input fields are activated.

This bug is caused by the fact that for both of the labels, the `for` value is `email` (so a copy/paste error?) but there is no element with an `id` of `email` - the first one does have a `name` equal to `email`, but that's not what counts.